# How can do array map inside methods in vuejs

Tags: arrays, dictionary, vue.js

How can ı equalize my array ıd and my value ıd and access value.name I didn't do it

This is my code:

```
activity(val) {
    var act = this.items.map(function (val) {
        if (element.ActivityID== val) {
            return element.ActivityName
        }

        return act
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?

```js
activity (val) {
  const activity = this.items.find(item => item.ActivityID === val)

  return activity && activity.ActivityName
}
```

This just finds the item with the corresponding `ActivityID` and then returns its `ActivityName`.

Your original code contained several possible mistakes:

1. Two different things called `val`.
2. `element` doesn't appear to be defined.
3. The `return act` was inside the `map` callback. The `activity` method itself wasn't returning anything.
4. Not really clear why you were using `map` to find a single item. `map` is used to create a new array with the same length as the original array with each item in the new array determined by the equivalent item in the original array. It 'maps' the items of the input array to the items in the output array.